# Remove previous String entries

Tags: java, search, arraylist

Not exactly sure how to phrase this question. 
I'm writing a spell check program, that reads words from a text file. These words are then added to an ArrayList of type:

```
ArrayList<String> dictionaryList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, the program runs as an endless loop (until 'q' is typed), and the user is prompted to search for a word. If the word can be found, the program returns a simple "Found word" message.

Otherwise; take the search term and generate variations of that word. These variations are added to the list:

```
ArrayList<String> allSimilarWords = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For instance, the word "**coffei**" would generate a series of "similar words", one of them being "**coffee**" (a word in the English language).

Now, seeing that I have both a list of all the dictionary words, as well as a list of the similar words, the program checks if words in **allSimilarWords** are contained in **dictionaryList**.

I have checked my **generateSimilarWords**-method, and it works as expected.

However, there is a problem when asking for user input the **second** time. The first time (typing "coffei" (where **coffee** is in the dictionary list)), the program produces the following output:

```
Enter search term: 
coffei
Suggestion for similar words: 
-coffee
```

Since this is an endless loop, the program asks me to enter another word. Now, if I type "banaan" (where **banana** is in the dictionary), the program produces the following output:

```
Enter search term: 
banaan
Suggestion for similar words: 
-coffee
-banana
```

Hence, it "remembers" me searching for **coffei**, and provides "coffee" as a suggested word, in addition to the word "banana". I've been trying to figure out why this happens, but cannot find my error. Any help would be highly appreciated. Following is the code:

**CODE**

```
//GETTING SIMILAR WORD ARRAYLIST
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getSimilarWords(String searchWord) {
    this.searchWord = searchWord;
    char[] wordAsCharacterArray = searchWord.toCharArray(); //Convert search String to a character array

    //Call helper methods to add the suggested similar words to the similarWordArrayList
    similarWordArrayList.add(charSwap(wordAsCharacterArray));   //Add swapped character suggestions
    similarWordArrayList.add(charRemove(wordAsCharacterArray)); //Add removed character suggestions
    similarWordArrayList.add(charAdd(wordAsCharacterArray)); //Add removed character suggestions
    similarWordArrayList.add(charReplace(wordAsCharacterArray)); //Add removed character suggestions

    return similarWordArrayList;
}
```

The **similarWordArrayList** is later "converted" to an ArrayList containing only String elements, as opposed to being a list of type ArrayList < ArrayList< String > >.

```
//Method to generate and suggest similar words
private void suggestWords(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> similarWords) {
    allSimilarWords = convertSingleList(similarWords);
    String currWord = "";

    outer: for(int i = 0; i < allSimilarWords.size(); i++) { //Iterate through the list of similar words
        currWord = allSimilarWords.get(i); //Set current similar word to a String variable
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(currWord.equalsIgnoreCase(allSimilarWords.get(j))) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        if(myDictionaryList.contains(currWord)) {
            System.out.println("-" + currWord);
        }

    }
}
```

Method for finding the String:

```
public void findString(String word) {
    searchTerm = word;
    if(myDictionaryList.contains(word)) {    //If found
        System.out.println("Found word!");  //Notify
    }
    else {
        //Find all similar words
        System.out.println("Suggestions for similar words: ");
        similarWords = handler.getSimilarWords(searchTerm);
        suggestWords(similarWords);
    }
}
```

Any help on how I can fix this, so that the program only prints out suggested words based on the LAST search term (and not remembering previously suggested words), is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me which variable gives final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the first thing, you have to do is to clear your arraylist before adding words to it.

```
//GETTING SIMILAR WORD ARRAYLIST
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getSimilarWords(String searchWord) {
    this.searchWord = searchWord;
    char[] wordAsCharacterArray = searchWord.toCharArray(); //Convert search String to a character array

    //Clear the list before adding words
    similarWordArrayList.clear();

    //Call helper methods to add the suggested similar words to the similarWordArrayList
    similarWordArrayList.add(charSwap(wordAsCharacterArray));   //Add swapped character suggestions
    similarWordArrayList.add(charRemove(wordAsCharacterArray)); //Add removed character suggestions
    similarWordArrayList.add(charAdd(wordAsCharacterArray)); //Add removed character suggestions
    similarWordArrayList.add(charReplace(wordAsCharacterArray)); //Add removed character suggestions

    return similarWordArrayList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, it still gives me the previously suggested word, upon typing a second search term. :S

Comment: But the way @DirkNm suggested is the way to do that. May be the place will be the different. But you have to clear the list before forming those words.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It helped me realise that I had to clear the ArrayList **allSimilarWords** (in the suggestWords()-method).